# How to run a command in a node app deployed to Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I'm trying to learn how to deploy my apps and the teacher told us to use Heroku. I have a Node.js app that uses `readline` library to read `a` and `b` and outputs the sum of two numbers to the console and the cycle repeats. Is there a way to pass that data to the app when its deployed to Heroku and running? I found only a heroku-cli command `heroku ps:exec` but i don't know how to "enter" the running node process from there.

I know this exercise doesn't make sense but for me it's a hard question. Thank You for any help.

Comment: Heroku is for deploying web apps, not running console commands.

Comment: You can use [`heroku run`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-run) to run a command interactively, e.g. `heroku run bash` or `heroku run node my_script.js`, but this will run in a separate [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) from the dyno running your web application, assuming you have one. Why does your instructor want you to use Heroku?